# Laravel 5.5+ API Exception Handing (JSON) - what's the best way to do this?

Tags: php, laravel, api, exception, laravel-passport

I have been searching most of the day for some additional info, guides and advice on this but so far its been quite limited. I am creating a Laravel 5.6 API with passport and need to implement some robust exception handing.

So far I have edited the exception handler class to something along these lines:

```
if ($request->wantsJson()) {

    //model not found
    if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        return response()->json(
            [
                'errors' => [
                    'status' => 404,
                    'title' => 'Resource not found',
                    'detail' => $exception->getMessage()
                ]
            ],
            404);
    }
}
```

This sends back JSON errors to the user as intended. I have also included catches for model not found, page not found, missing API scope and then finally a fallback for anything else.

For areas of code where I know there may be input errors by the end user, I have implemented try catches where I can make convert the error message into something more user friendly, re-throw it and then have it sent back to the user with the above code.

```
try{
    $to = new Carbon(request('created_to'));
} catch (\Exception $e){
    throw new \Exception('Date time could not be parsed into recognised format.', 400, $e);
}
```

I have not yet implemented any request/form validation exceptions but expect this will be similar using Laravels message bag feature.

I have got something usable here but would love to know your thoughts and if anyone has any advice, link to guides or other tips they can share to make it better. Of course, if its all wrong I am happy to start fresh!
I feel like there must be either some well developed libraries or something native to the framework that I am missing.

**Edit**

A few resources I have found:

[Middleware to ensure always json response](https://gist.github.com/meSingh/c90c5abc81a9cc0687a62a84eb2c696b) - If `Accept: application/json` is not included in the header, the user will get html back. This middleware adds this header into all HTML requests.

[Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api) - This package seems to have once been the goto for all things Laravel API. However it seems since more recent versions much of it is redundant. There may still be usable elements of it but there appear to be many issues/bugs related to using it with 5.5+.

[Blog post focusing on heimdal error handler](http://esbenp.github.io/2017/01/14/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-3/) - This is the closest I have found to a dedicated API exception handler package. Again its quite old and has not been updated for a while.